# JavaFX - Call UI updating methods with pause inbetween

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, methods, thread-sleep

I am working on a **JavaFx** school project at the moment where I try to move an `imageView` across a `GridPane`. The movement should be *visualized/updated* on the UI sequentially.

I tried `AnimationTimers` and `Threads` and everything but I am not that experienced in this field. I start a `Thread` in my `PlaygroundController`, and call a sleep everytime at the end of a method.

In the second code snippet I created an object of the `PlaygroundController` class and call the methods three times in a row. I am aiming at a behaviour that moves the `ImageView` 1 column to the right with the `moveRight()` method, pauses for one second and then moves down calling the `moveDown()` method and so on.

With my code it does all 3 methods together after a 3 seconds delay.

```
private Thread thread;
public PlaygroundController() { 
    thread = new Thread();
    thread.start();

}

public void run(ActionEvent evt) throws InterruptedException {  
    Level1Solution level = new Level1Solution(this);

}

public void moveRight() throws InterruptedException {   
    if(GridPane.getColumnIndex(avatarIcon) < 10) {
        GridPane.setColumnIndex(avatarIcon, GridPane.getColumnIndex(avatarIcon) +1);

    }else{
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Fehler!");
        alert.setHeaderText("Weiter geht es nicht!");
        alert.setOnHidden(evt -> Platform.exit());
        alert.show();
    }
    avatarColumn = GridPane.getColumnIndex(avatarIcon);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Second snippet:

```
package controller;

public class Level1Solution {


    PlaygroundController solution;

    public Level1Solution(PlaygroundController solution) throws InterruptedException {

        this.solution = solution;
        solution.moveRight();
        solution.moveDown();
        solution.moveRight();

    }

}
```

Comment: Use a `Timeline`. Don't try to use threads at all for this.

Comment: Okay thank you for the answer, I would have to read myself into that first, but could you tell me where to use the Timeline? In the constructor of Level1Solution where I call the methods or inside every method?

Comment: Use it in the constructor of `Level1Solution`. Just put each method call into the event handler for a `KeyFrame`. (And get rid of the call to `Thread.sleep()` in `moveRight()`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Level1Solution` constructor is presumably executed on the FX Application Thread. It calls three methods on the `PlaygroundController` instance, each of which (presumably) changes the position of a UI element and then pauses the current (i.e. FX Application) thread for one second.

Note the Thread you create in `PlaygroundController` doesn't really do anything: it has no `Runnable` and doesn't override its own `run()` method, so it basically does nothing. You start that thread - so it executes its `run()` method in the background, and it will immediately exit (because it has nothing to do).

The FX Application Thread is responsible for rendering the UI. Because you execute the `Level1Solution` constructor on the FX Application Thread, that UI cannot be rendered until that constructor is completed; i.e. after three seconds the UI will reflect all the changes you made to it.

For reasons like this, you should *never* block the FX Application Thread. Note also that the actual changes to the UI *must* be made on that thread.

To execute code on the FX Application Thread at specific time points, you should use some kind of [animation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html). For your use case, a `Timeline` would work well; just define key frames for each of the time points, with an event handler that calls the method:

```
public class Level1Solution {


    PlaygroundController solution;

    public Level1Solution(PlaygroundController solution) throws InterruptedException {

        this.solution = solution;

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), e -> solution.moveRight()),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> solution.moveDown()),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> solution.moveRight()));

        timeline.play();
    }

}
```

And of course remove the `Thread` and the pauses from the `PlaygroundController`:

```
public PlaygroundController() { 
}

public void run(ActionEvent evt) throws InterruptedException {  
    Level1Solution level = new Level1Solution(this);

}

public void moveRight() throws InterruptedException {   
    if(GridPane.getColumnIndex(avatarIcon) < 10) {
        GridPane.setColumnIndex(avatarIcon, GridPane.getColumnIndex(avatarIcon) +1);

    }else{
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Fehler!");
        alert.setHeaderText("Weiter geht es nicht!");
        alert.setOnHidden(evt -> Platform.exit());
        alert.show();
    }
    avatarColumn = GridPane.getColumnIndex(avatarIcon);

    // never block the UI thread:
    // Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

---

If you have a specific requirement that the `Level1Controller` constructor *must* call those three methods, and not handle the pauses itself in any way, then it gets quite a bit more difficult. One approach would be for the methods you are calling to submit a task to a single threaded executor, with the task they submit performing the UI action and then pausing for some time. The pause on the single thread would ensure that there would be some time before any other task could be executed. Note in this case that the tasks would be on a background thread, so the actual changes to the UI would have to be wrapped in a call to `Platform.runLater(...)` to execute them on the FX Application Thread.

This would all look something like:

```
public class PlaygroundController {

    private ExecutorService exec ;

    public PlaygroundController() { 
        // single thread executor using a daemon thread 
        // (so it will not prevent application exit)
        exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(runnable -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t ;
        });
    }

    public void run(ActionEvent evt) throws InterruptedException {  
        Level1Solution level = new Level1Solution(this);

    }

    public void moveRight() throws InterruptedException {   

        Runnable task = () -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                if(GridPane.getColumnIndex(avatarIcon) < 10) {
                    GridPane.setColumnIndex(avatarIcon, GridPane.getColumnIndex(avatarIcon) +1);

                } else {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
                    alert.setTitle("Fehler!");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Weiter geht es nicht!");
                    alert.setOnHidden(evt -> Platform.exit());
                    alert.show();
                }
                avatarColumn = GridPane.getColumnIndex(avatarIcon);
            });
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        };

        exec.submit(task);
    }

    // ...

}
```

and then just

```
public class Level1Solution {


    PlaygroundController solution;

    public Level1Solution(PlaygroundController solution) throws InterruptedException {

        this.solution = solution;
        solution.moveRight();
        solution.moveDown();
        solution.moveRight();

    }

}
```

should achieve the desired result. This approach seems a little overly complex though: the solution above with the animation is far preferable.

Comment: This works perfect, thank you!
But is there still a way I would only have to call the methods in the constructor and create the Timeline and KeyFrames within the methods. 
This project is part of a "Gamifying the learning of Programming" research, so I am trying to simplify the Level1Solution constructor, so the "user/player" would only have to call the methods and everything else is done in the PlaygroundController class.

Comment: @Ridvan Added a possible solution where the methods themselves handle their own delays. This feels like a very unnatural approach though.